# A contest inequality

Tags: inequality

The following inequality appeared in the AMTI contest in India, which was held a couple of days ago.

> If $x$ and $y$ are positive reals such that $x^{2014}+y^{2014}=1$ prove that
>
> $\displaystyle \left(\sum_{k=1}^{1007} \frac{1 + x^{2k}}{1+x^{4k}}\right)\left(\sum_{k=1}^{1007} \frac{1 + y^{2k}}{1+y^{4k}}\right) < \frac1{(1-x)(1-y)}.$

I have tried grouping terms and have tried A.M-G.M inequality in various ways. Nothing I do seems to work. Would someone kindly post a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: replace 2014 by, say, 2 or 6 or 10, see whether you can do those. Maybe 4. **Extremely** unlikely that this depends on the size of 2014, just something like it being twice odd...

Comment: I have tried that.The case with 2 is trivial. Even with just two terms(case where 2014 is replaced by 4),I have no idea what to do.

Comment: Did you get the solution for this problem ?